# how to get the posterior probability of topics in LDA model using gensim?

Tags: python, gensim, lda

I want to apply the "bayes factor" method in *Bybee, Leland and Kelly, Bryan T. and Manela, Asaf and Xiu, Dacheng, Business News and Business Cycles, forthcoming in the Journal of Finance*. Therefore, I would like to calculate the posterior probability of a LDA model with selected topic numbers, so that I can compare different models with various topic numbers.
I try to use the "LdaState" in gensim, however, I failed to get the right parameters.
Can anyone kindly tell me how to use the "LdaState"?

For example:

```
eta = lda0.eta
lamda = LdaState(eta, shape=((i, 10),)).get_lambda()
```

```
File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharmCE2023.2\scratches\scratch_10.py", line 71, in run
    lamda = LdaState(eta, shape=((i, 10),)).get_lambda()
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\gensim\models\ldamodel.py", line 174, in __init__
    self.sstats = np.zeros(shape, dtype=dtype)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'tuple' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

I appreciate the help of jejemalani, and I still need some detailed examples. Please see the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Changing your code to the following should fix your problem, given `i` is an integer.

```
eta = lda0.eta
lamda = LdaState(eta, shape=(i, 10)).get_lambda()
```

Taken from the [Gensim LDA Model Docs](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/ldamodel.html)

```
classgensim.models.ldamodel.LdaState(eta, shape, dtype=<class 'numpy.float32'>)
```

Bases: SaveLoad

**Parameters**

- `eta (numpy.ndarray)` – The prior probabilities assigned to each term.
- `shape (tuple of (int, int))` – Shape of the sufficient statistics: (number of topics to be found, number of terms in the vocabulary).
- `dtype (type)` – Overrides the numpy array default types.

`dtype` is optional. Make sure the rest of the parameters you pass match the above.

Comment: I appreciate your help! I still have two questions. ① Does the lambda statistic really mean the posterior probability of the LDA model? ② As instructed by PyCharm, the shape should be "tuple[tuple[int, int]]". Can you provide a more detailed example of this parameter? Thanks a lot!

Comment: 1. lambda (LDA model) refers to the topic-word distribution and not the posterior probability of the entire model. The posterior probability involves multiple parameters.

Comment: 2. `shape`, according to the [docs](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/ldamodel.html) is a simple tuple in python with both integer values.
Example:
`x = number of topics to be found`,
`y = number of terms in the library`,
`shape = (x,y)`

Comment: Please update your original question if this was useful.

Comment: Thank you for the answer to the first question. However, regarding the second question, shape refers to the shape of the sufficient statistics.  Its format is tuple[tuple (int, int)], but not a simple tuple. To solve this problem, I think I should have a more grounded knowledge of probability theory.